# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value reading JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode6, option-type

people, I can not understand why, but this problem (unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value) happens in this line:

var dict: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary

see the code:

import Foundation

class ProdutoService {

```
// return a produtos Array
class func getProdutos() -> Array<Produto> {

    var produtos: Array<Produto> = []

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var p = Produto()
        p.nome = "Produto \(i)"
        p.desc1 = "Descrição \(i)"
        p.desc2 = "Descrição \(i)"

        produtos.append(p)
    }

    return produtos
}

// get from JSON
class func getProdutosByJson() -> Array<Produto> {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("produtos", ofType: "json")!
    let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)

    let produtos = parserJson(data!)

    return produtos
}

class func parserJson(data: NSData) -> Array<Produto> {

    if (data.length == 0) {
        println("NSData vazio")
        return []
    }

    var produtos: Array<Produto> = []

    // read JSON and convert to Dictionary
    var error: NSError?
    var dict: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary

    // read the structure Produtos and return a array with JSON content
    var jsonProdutos: NSDictionary = dict["produtos"] as NSDictionary
    var arrayProdutos: NSArray = jsonProdutos["produto"] as NSArray

    // Array produtos

    for obj:AnyObject in arrayProdutos {
        var dict = obj as NSDictionary
        var produto = Produto()
        produto.nome = dict["nome"] as String
        produto.desc1 = dict["desc1"] as String
        produto.desc2 = dict["desc2"] as String
        produtos.append(produto)
    }

    return produtos
}
```

}

Comment: I believe this means that your JSON was not parseable as an NSDictionary structure. It may be empty, or perhaps it might be an NSArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONObject with data seems to return NIL, because the data may be invalid.
Check the content of the error parameter!

As a solution, you should check the JSON datasource before reading from it. Use the NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject member function.